# Title-less objects not working?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

According to [the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/titleless-objects/), title-less objects can be created by leaving the field "og:title" empty.
When I publish an activity with a title-less object the activity is created and I receive an activity id but the activity is not shown on Facebook.
When I type the URL of the activity (i.e. http://www.facebook.com/USER_ID/activity/ACTIVITY_ID) Facebook says "The page you requested was not found.".

If I update the object and set a title all the activities appears and work fine. If I update the object and empty the title, the activities disappear again.

Is someone successfully using titleless objects ? Has anyone solved this problem ?

Note : I also opened [a bug at Facebook](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/128913220599051).

Comment: Does the activity instance ID you get back from the API when you POST the action work when you try to retrieve the details via the API?

Comment: No I got a blank screen. And when I update the object and set a title everything works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook said titleless objects are not supported anymore: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/128913220599051

Answer (score 0):

Apparently objects without a title need the description property set otherwise they are not shown on the users activity.